# Rails overwriting params value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trello

I'm trying to up receive updates on my [Trello](http://trello.com) model when a change occurs, which I'm using their [webhooks](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/webhook) for. The problem is that one of the parameter's name is "action", which seems to be overwritten by Rails depending on the value in the Routes.rb. Is there any way to avoid this or do I just have to live with it?

---

**Routes.rb**

```
  match "/trello" => "trello_updates#index", via: [:get,:post]
```

---

**Webhook reponse**

```
Parameters: {"model"=>{...},"action"=>"index"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a middleware in initializers and update the params coming from trello webhooks. like below -

```
class TrelloWebhooks

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    trello_action = request.params['action']
    request.update_param('trello_action', trello_action)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    [status, headers, response]
  end

end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'TrelloWebhooks'
```

Comment: I'm still fairly new to the Rails environment, so I'm unsure of where to put this code?

Comment: @Niels Sønderbæk, you can copy this code to a file in `config/initializers/trello_webhooks.rb`

Comment: That gives me the following error: `trello_webhooks.rb:17:in '<top (required)>': undefined method 'use' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Hi, I doesn't provide an error anymore, however, it just sets the new param 'trello_action' to nil and the value request.params always seems to be empty.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but it's a POST request?

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the code from Vishnu, which is the accepted answer to make it work with a post request, so if you have a post request, you need to fetch the params out from the body of the response instead:

```
class TrelloWebhooks

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    body = JSON.parse(request.body.string)
    trello_action = body["action"]
    request.update_param('trello_action', trello_action)
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    [status, headers, response]
  end

end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use 'TrelloWebhooks'
```